# How to remove devices from stackdriver policy notification list

Tags: stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

My StackDriver Alerting Policy setup (for the Cloud Console mobile app) has two devices with the exact same name. Only one appears to actually deliver notifications to my phone, so I can never tell which one is the correct one to deliver it to my phone.

Where does this list of devices come from? I only own one iPhone....I did get my old one replaced by Apple but that was more than a year ago, maybe it's "held on to it" somehow"?

And how can I clean it up and delete old devices?

You can see the screenshot of what the identical devices looks like, below:
[image: Alerting Policy showing the Notifications has two options with identical emails]

My workaround has been two set up two notifications, each pointing at a different "same email", to ensure it gets routed to both the correct (and incorrect) targets.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the device from your Gmail profile

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6264236?hl=en#remove_device

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just went in and removed the old iPhone which was still in my Gmail Profile. Unfortunately, both iPhones still appear to show up in StackDriver...is there perhaps a delay for the two systems to sync up?